# How to check for required fields before closing window?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have JSF page, and I want to create button for save and close, but if user dont enter all required fields to hold. 
So this will do exactly what I want, but it will not close window.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{projectsControllerCreate.create}"
               value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsSaveLink}" />
```

And this will close window no metter what is entered.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{projectsControllerCreate.create}"
                 value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsSaveLink}"  
                 onclick="window.close()"/>
```

And I have added JS Exit() to button but it doesn't work?

```
function Exit() {
    var x = #{projectsControllerCreate.selected.projectName.length()
    }

    if (x > 0) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

```
<p:commandButton action="#{projectsControllerCreate.create}"
                 value="#{bundle.CreateProjectsSaveLink}"  
                 onclick="Exit()" />
```

Can I check on create if everything is OK and than send `window.close();` command?

```
public String create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ProjectsCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with the timing of the render of the markup to the browser vs the value in the backing bean. You should be performing the evaluation server-side

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.
One is you can close the window from you ManagedBean's Action method itself using Primefaces [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html). Example [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml)

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("CLOSE_YOUR_WINDOW_HERE");
```

Second way is to check if validation failed using the Client side callback of `RequestContext`, which is `args`.

`oncomplete="(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed){CLOSE_YOUR_WINDOW_HERE}`"

Remember to use `args` in `oncomplete` of your `p:commandButton` only. Because `args` will be available as part of your AjaxCall response, so using above in `onclick` will/may return `args` as `null`.

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that OP has a dialog.

Comment: Sorry I assumed its a Primefaces dialog.I'll change it. The technique is same for window also though.